# Why is a non-boolean variable being compared to "FALSE" in the condition of the while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {...}
```

In the given line of code, two things are happening in a while loop. The first is the assignment of `fgetcsv($file)` to `$line` (which is an array, `fgetcsv($file)` returns an array ) and the other one is the condition check: `while($line !== FALSE)`

**My question is that $line is not a Boolean variable. So how can it be compared to FALSE?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$line` becomes `false` when [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) reaches the end of the file.

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, **including end of file**.